# Draw (2D)Image in OpenGL

Tags: c++, image, opengl, glfw

I'm stuck at simply drawing an image into an OpenGL window.

I'm using GLEW and GLFW.

My code looks like this (part of it):

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

GLuint shader = CreateShaders("something"); // Compiles and does OpenGL-Stuff (I checked - it works)
glClearColor(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(shader);
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

//g_vertex_buffer_data and g_uv_buffer_data are from the tutorial
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint uvbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_uv_buffer_data), g_uv_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

// Data is a 1200 x 1000 x 3 char array (for testing purposes containing the mandelbrot set)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1200, 1000, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Data);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(vfShader, "MandelbrotImg"), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 430 core

in vec2 UV;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D MandelbrotImg;

void main()
{
    color = texture(MandelbrotImg, UV).rgb;
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 UV;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);
    UV = vertexUV;
}
```

By the way: The image is created by a compute shader, so at least this works (but I also tested here with just some simple C++-generated data to see *anything*...)

Comment: OK guys, I now FINALLY see something. Doesn't look like it should, but that is probably the color components that should be floats. I'll try that now

Comment: well... since (as @Rabbid76 pointed out) you're using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as the texture format, floats aren't what is expected. Just try filling `Data` with something reasonable so you can verify that the data you're generating is actually what's being sampled.

Comment: OK, so I fill Data with a picture of the mandelbrot set. I also display it via CImg, where it looks as it should. When I use GLuints I can "somewhat" see the set, but barely (only some pixels seem right and serveral pictures seem to "mix"). When I use floats, I can see the set in mostly black and the outlines in some colors. Also the texture is drawn on a cube (I used that form the tutorial and wanted to change it later to a rectangle). The other two sides I can see have more of a light-gray touch but look otherwise the same. So is it an issue with g_vertex_buffer_data or g_uv_buffer_data?

Comment: If you're seeing something that resembles the correct pattern / shape of your source data, then it might be an issue of scale. If you're taking image data that's in the 0..1 float range, and not correctly transforming that into a 0..255 range (since you're using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`) then, at best, you'll wind up with something that's very dim.

Comment: So, to be clear: with a floating-point texture format, every color component ranges from 0..1. Anything > 1 is clamped to 1. If you're using that data for a `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` image, then you're going to wind up with some weird output. (A `1` in a float texture is the same as a `255` in a BYTE texture.) Loop through your image data, multiple everything * 256, and see what happens. Gotta go start making Thanksgiving dinner for the kids.

Comment: I changed GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to GL_FLOAT. Looping through the image data just brightens the image. I'll try the same thing tomorrow with GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. But at least I finally see a picture now. That's a good place to start looking for errors, so thank you very much. But my brain is broken for today and I'll sleep now. Happy Thanksgiving

Comment: Oh, I can relate. Glad I could help. (Probably should've moved this to chat earlier.)